# onTap event only regonized by widget behind button

Tags: flutter

I have a strange issue with my `BottomAppBar` and an overlapping `ElevatedButton`.

If I click on the upper half of the `+ Button` the onTap event is fired for the widget behind the `+ Button`. I tried different things but non are working, help is very appreciated, thanks :)

[image]

`HomePage`

```
return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedIndex,
        children: _pages,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const _BottomAppBar(),
    );
```

`_BottomAppBar`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return BottomAppBar(
      child: IconTheme(
        data: IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
              Positioned(
                top: -30,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  onPressed: () {
                    ...
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: const CircleBorder(),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      primary: lightGreen),
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                    tooltip: 'Home',
                    iconSize: 28,
                    icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/svg/home-aktiv.svg'
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      ...
                    }),
                IconButton(
                    tooltip: 'Profile',
                    iconSize: 32,
                    icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/svg/profil-aktiv.svg'
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      ...
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I guess it has to do with the negative positioning. One thing you could try is wrapping the `ElevatedButton` in an `InkWell` and using that to catch the events, that might be handled differently.

Comment: replace your button with GestureDetector or inkwell

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a `FloatingActionButton`?

```
return Scaffold(
  body: IndexedStack(
    index: _selectedIndex,
    children: _pages,
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: _BottomAppBar(),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
);
```